# A simple list simulation in python

Tags: python

```
lists = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
nos = [4, 4, 1, 1]

for idx, ln in enumerate(zip(lists,nos)):
    l, n = ln[0], ln[1]       
    in_nos = range(1, n+1)    
    for indx, in_no in enumerate(in_nos):  
        out_no = ??? ### **I need an expression to get out_no here** 
        print out_no
```

Without modifying anything except the ??? after out_no, I need to print out the numbers from 1 to the sum of the numbers in `nos` i.e.:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I tried as:

`out_no = idx*n + indx + 1`

which resulted in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1
1
```

Which `out_no` would give me the correct result?

Comment: i did it as out_no = idx*n + indx + 1

Comment: You are really over complicating this

Comment: Yeah, you also need to define EXACTLY what it is that you want. It seems like you want to print out numbers from 1 to the sum of the numbers in nos. That's just a guess based on the example though.

Comment: @CrazyCasta yes you have my question clearly.

Comment: What does `lists` have to do with any of this?

Comment: @IanAuld you can avoid the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're allowed to change, the simple way would of course be:

```
lists = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
nos = [4, 4, 1, 1]

a = 0

for idx, ln in enumerate(zip(lists,nos)):
    l, n = ln[0], ln[1]       
    in_nos = range(1, n+1)    
    for indx, in_no in enumerate(in_nos):  
        out_no = a+indx+1
        print out_no   ##The result should be HERE
    a += n
```

Assuming you can only change out_no, you could do:

```
lists = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
nos = [4, 4, 1, 1]

for idx, ln in enumerate(zip(lists,nos)):
    l, n = ln[0], ln[1]       
    in_nos = range(1, n+1)    
    for indx, in_no in enumerate(in_nos):  
        out_no = sum(nos[0:+idx])+indx+1
        print out_no   ##The result should be HERE
```

Ok, as IanAuld pointed out, if you can just scrap everything but nos there are simpler solutions, for instance:

```
nos = [4, 4, 1, 1]
for i in range(sum(nos)): print i+1
```

Comment: This is really over complicating the solution

Comment: @IanAuld How is this overcomplicated the solution? I'm taking what he gave us and making minimal changes. Please be more constructive, saying "This is really over complicating the solution" without being more specific is not very helpful.

Comment: @CrazyCasta I'm using your 2nd solution, adding 1 after indx

Comment: You described the problem yourself, OP needs to find the sum of the list `nos`, `N`, and print the numbers in the `range(1, N + 1)`. So instead of using whatever the OP made which is terribly unpythonic and overcomplicated you should have pointed him towards: `for i in range(1, sum(nos) + 1): print(i)`

Comment: @IanAuld yes this thing I know, but I need to get the required numbers in the place I pointed out in my program using the given things...

Comment: @Borys Your expected output is a sequence of numbers in numerical order from 1 to `sum(nos)` inclusive. If that's not what you want you need fix your question.

Comment: @IanAuld yes, you are right in terms of the required numbers, but I need to get those numbers using index and idx they were given conditions in my question

Comment: @IanAuld You're getting overly picky here. I think it's fairly clear what Borys wants. Yes it could be polished up, but we really don't need this constant "you're overcomplicating things" bit.

Comment: @Borys IanAuld is suggesting that you should specify in your question that the only acceptable solution is that which provides a (presumably side effect free) expression for out_no in place of the ???

Comment: @CrazyCasta okay I did it!

Comment: @Borys I just modified the question to make it clear. You have two requirements in your question: 1. that you modify nothing except the ??? after out_no and 2. that you print out the numbers from 1 to sum(nos). You need to specify both of these requirements in one statement, or a list in one place. Finally the requirements should be outside your code (i.e. not comments inside it).